# would have + past participle presumption

Tags: grammar

Could we use "would have +  past participle" to express the speak's belief about something ?

For example :

- I'm sure he would have killed her.
- He definitely would have been listening when we fought yesterday.

Comment: To improve this question, **what is "pp"**?  Present perfect, past perfect, present participle, past participle, perfectly pleasurable, probably patrician, ...?

Comment: past participle

Comment: Please edit your question to make this more clear .. thank you and keep contributing!

Comment: Your first example doesn't work, at least not without some context.  If you want to simply express belief that something happened: then it should be: I am sure he killed her.   IMHO using "would have" on its own like this is very strange/odd, not idiomatic. I would expect that to be followed by a conditional, for example "if the police hadn't stopped him", or perhaps if the context makes it clear that something prevented him from killing her.  The second is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use would have + past principle.

It can have several things:

- Being a conditional (describes a situation that didn’t happen and imagines the results of this situation)
- Talk about something you wanted to do but didn’t

Here the sentence are a conditional.

An example in context:

> If she saw him, I’m sure she would have killed her

Here its describing a situation that didn’t happen an imaging the results of such a situation. But here the written expresses more certainty that that is what happened, but as it didn’t happen you can’t be 100% sure.

Comment: I didn't mean that,  I mean if we could use "could have +pp " to talk about what the speaker really believe happened but he don't have an evidence, for example :  "We saw a police helicopter overhead yesterday morning ,They would have been looking for those bank robbers.  "

Comment: @is Yes you can use that

Comment: @thedev09 - yes you can do that. However, while "been" is the past participle of "be", "been looking" as a phrase is the present or past perfect of "look", so it doesn't really fit your original question.